# Special character/ Unicode / special symbol to word from php

Tags: php, ms-word, converters, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I'm using [COM](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php) for generate word document from PHP. i have a big issue when convert character for send to word bookmark template generating useless Chinese character and some number.

here is what i have string value in php - `Brüel & Kjær`

this is the text of word document after generate -  `Brüel & Kjær1墄`

here is my converting way in php:

```
$text="Brüel & Kjær";
$text = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8",$text);
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
$text=html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

this is how adding COM bookmark variable to value :

```
$PHPWord = new COM("word.application", NULL, CP_UTF8);
$PHPWord->Documents->Open(realpath($template));
$bookmark = $PHPWord->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("bookmark1");
$bookmark = $bookmark->Range;
$bookmark->Text=$text;
$PHPWord->Documents[1]->SaveAs('temp/' . $template);
```

i beleve the character converting issue in my code. but i searched on internet, i couldn't found working solution for my problem. can you please help to solve this.

is their way to send html to this bookmark or any convert ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG almost done with this :

```
$text="Brüel & Kjær";

$PHPWord = new COM("word.application", NULL, CP_UTF8);
```

replaced to :

```
$PHPWord = new COM("word.application");
$PHPWord->Documents->Open(realpath($template));
$bookmark = $PHPWord->ActiveDocument->Bookmarks("bookmark1");
$bookmark = $bookmark->Range;
$bookmark->Text=html_entity_decode($text);
$PHPWord->Documents[1]->SaveAs('temp/' . $template);
```